# How to append input to axios call endpoint using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Have an axios get call endpoint and need to append a user input to the end of the endpoint to retrieve the record based on user input.  I want to find all records with a certain ID that the user input. How do I append the user input to the axios endpoint using Reactjs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you want to send as query params:

```
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
```

or you can append it in url like this:

```
axios.get(`/getAllUser/${id}`)
```